# sonar scanner throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to scan a project with sonar scanner but getting this call & error:

```
     mvn verify sonar:sonar "-Dsonar.login=<login>" -DskipTests
```

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project test: Unable to load component class org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSensor: ExceptionInInitializerError: java.lang.reflect.Inaccessible
    ObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1bfbbc53
```

I'm using following mvn plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1.2184</version>
        </plugin>
```

and Java 17 with a amazon corretto 17 jdk

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
```

My IDE is an IntelliJ IDEA with Project JDK set to amazon corretto 17

I tried downgrading the maven plugin and the jdk as I read about so before but it did not solve my Problem.
Are there any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What is your SonarQube Server version? You should be using 9.1 as you have Java 17 and sonar-maven-plugin 3.9.1 according to this post:

https://community.sonarsource.com/t/support-java-17-in-the-sonar-maven-plugin/51931

Comment: Hi,
I'm using this: [INFO] SonarQube version: 8.4.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jenkins, could be a solution the Scaner with a JDK 8.

For instance:

```
stage('Sonar Report') {
            tools {
                jdk "jdk-1.8-latest"
            }
            steps {
                echo "Sonar Report"
                bat 'mvn -version'
                bat 'mvn sonar:sonar'
            }
        }
```

It was for us the solution without Migration/Update.